# Polish characters have different weight

Tags: html, fonts, polish

I've bought html template -> https://themeforest.net/item/bredh-multipurpose-web-hosting-with-whmcs-template/23474111 , now I need to add there some polish pharses but the problem is that some of the polish characters look different.

Font used: "Poppins"

[image]

[image]

Does someone knows how to eliminate this?

Comment: Use a font that supports Polish characters?

Answer (score 0):

I’m curious, how is Poppins included?

The version of Poppins hosted by Google Fonts includes support for Polish, so you could either download the files from there are replace it, or use the hosted Google Fonts version.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/92xu1b8h/

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
h1 {
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

.regular {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
</style>

<h1>
  <span class="regular">Zarejestruj się </span>
  <strong class="bold">całkowicie za darmo</strong>
</h1>
```

[image]